# Mocking window.get() with Jest

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs

The TypeScript class shown below accesses the `window` global:

```
class WindowEnv {
  get(varName: string): string {
    return (window as any)._env_[varName];
  }
}
```

This class is indirectly accessed by a React component called `Headlines`. I am trying to test this component by mocking the values stored in the `window` global. Here's my test:

```
// Set API_URL in window environment
(window as any)._env_ = {
  API_URL: 'http://localhost:8080',
};

describe('<Headlines />', () => {
  test('renders correctly', async () => {
    const { findByTestId, findByText } = render(<Headlines />);
    expect(await findByText('Headlines')).toBeTruthy();

    // expect 4 headlines
    const headlineList = await findByTestId('headline-list');
    const headlines = headlineList.querySelectorAll('tbody tr');
    expect(headlines.length).toBe(4);
  });
});
```

However the test breaks saying that it can't find the window global:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'API_URL' of undefined
```

What's the best way to mock the `window` global?

Comment: *This class is indirectly accessed by a React component called Headlines* - where? The question doesn't contain the code that causes the problem. It's unclear whether `window` is undefined or else. You have `_env_[varName]` in one place and `_env_.API_URL` in another (a dot).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

inside the describe test block you can write the mock for the window object and the set environment value to it

```
  describe('<Headlines />', () => {
      const envValue = {
        API_URL: 'http://localhost:8080',
      };
    
      Object.defineProperty(window, '_env_', { value: envValue })
  
      test('renders correctly', async () => {
       //test logic of component
       ....
      });
    });
```